# Site is "downloading" a "download" file instead of loading the web page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a website hosted on AWS S3, and when I try to load the site, instead of showing the content, it just download a "download" file, no extension.

Here's the link:

[Link Here](http://redemidas.com.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/)

I've tried deleting the .haccess on the parent directory, but no luck at all.

Here is the index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php header('Content-Type:text/html'); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Rede Midas - Soluções em Pagamento</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="pagamentos, adquirentes, cartões de crédito, débito, boleto, maquininha, pos, tef, mobile, pagamentos, carteira virtual, gateway, processadora, credenciadora, credenciamento" />
  <meta name="description" content="A Rede Midas possui as melhores soluções para você processar cartões de débito e crédito.">


    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
    <meta property="og:url" content="index.html">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Rede Midas - Soluções em pagamentos">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Rede Midas Pagamentos">
    <meta property="og:description" content="A Rede Midas possui as melhores soluções para você processar cartões de débito e crédito em sua loja física ou virtual.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="images/social.html">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="800"> 
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="600">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.wixstatic.com/ficons/a6aeb6_aec733c370b24e4ab70877222fd28ddc.jpg" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <link href="css/flexslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/elegant-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/theme-aquatica.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>

        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie9.css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,300,600,700%7CRaleway:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loader">
            <div class="spinner">
              <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
              <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav class="top-bar">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row utility-menu">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="utility-inner clearfix">
                                <span class="alt-font"><i class="icon icon_phone"></i> Central de Atendimento: (11) 4302-3059
</span>
                                <span class="alt-font"><i class="icon icon_mail"></i> info@redemidas.com
</span>

                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="http://midas.cardtrue.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f" class="btn btn-primary login-button btn-xs" target="_blank">Acesse sua Conta</a>
                                    <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled btn-xs" data-mode="1">Junte-se a nós</a>                                 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of row-->


                    <div class="row nav-menu">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 columns">
                            <a href="index.php">
                                <img class="logo logo-light" alt="Logo" src="img/logo-light.png">
                                <img class="logo logo-dark" alt="Logo" src="img/logo-midas.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 columns">
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="index.php">INÍCIO</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#sobre">SOBRE</a>                                 
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a  href="#dispositivo">NOSSAS SOLUÇÕES</a>                                    
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a  href="http:www.redemidas.com/blog" target="_blank">Blog</a>                                    
                                </li>
                                 <li class="has-dropdown"><a  href="https://www.redemidas.com/blog/videos/" target="_blank">Vídeos</a>                                  
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="contato.php">CONTATO</a>                                  
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul class="social-icons text-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/redemidas">
                                        <i class="icon social_twitter"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/redemidas.net">
                                        <i class="icon social_facebook"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>                                                       
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of row-->

                    <div class="mobile-toggle">
                        <i class="icon icon_menu"></i>
                    </div>

                </div><!--end of container-->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
            <section class="hero-slider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li class="overlay">
                        <div class="background-image-holder parallax-background">
                            <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/hero17.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="container align-vertical">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                                    <h1 class="text-white">Controle e gestão em seus recebíveis de cartões de crédito e débito na ponta dos dedos!

</h1>
                                    <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled">CREDENCIE-SE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of container-->
                    </li><!--end of individual slide-->

                    <!--end of individual slide-->

                    <li class="overlay">
                        <div class="background-image-holder parallax-background">
                            <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/hero7.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="container align-vertical">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                                    <h1 class="text-white">A Rede Midas é a parceira que você buscava para aceitar cartões de débito e crédito.
</h1>
                                    <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-filled">CREDENCIE-SE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of container-->
                    </li><!--end of individual slide-->

                </ul>
            </section>
            <div align="center">
            <h2>Conheça a maquininha da Rede Midas</h2>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5LSCqRVtCQM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <section class="side-image text-heavy clearfix">
                <div class="image-container col-md-5 col-sm-3 pull-left">
                    <div class="background-image-holder">
                        <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/side2.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 content clearfix" id="dispositivo">
                            <h1>A maquininha</h1>
                            <p class="lead">
                                <strong>Como Funciona?</strong><br>
Ligue o dispositivo e comece a fazer transações imediatamente. Simplicidade, agilidade e sem burocracia.
                            </p>
                            <p class="lead">
                                <strong>Quem pode utilizar?</strong><br>
Para pessoas físicas ou jurídicas, que desejam aceitar cartões de débito e crédito.
                            </p>
 <p class="lead">
                                <strong>Requerimentos</strong><br>
Ligue para a rede Midas e explicaremos os passos para o seu credenciamento.
                            </p>      
<p class="lead">

                            <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary">Peça já a sua</a><br>                                          
                    </div><!--end of row-->

                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="duplicatable-content">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <h1>Conheça algumas vantagens</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of row-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-global"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Excelente sinal</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Não importa se é sinal de celular, internet ou linha telefônica, os terminais da Rede Midas completam a transação.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-tools-2"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Personalize</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Defina o nome do seu terminal e personalize a frase que é impressa no recibo do cliente.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">

                                    <i class="icon icon-clock"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Autonomia</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Mecanismo inteligente de bateria nos periodos de inatividade.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-presentation"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Controle absoluto</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Através do portal Rede Midas, é possível acompanhar diariamente todas as vendas realizadas.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-phone"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Mobilidade Total</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Muito mais mobilidade para efetuar suas vendas.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="feature feature-icon-large">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-document"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <h5>Extrato no dispositivo POS</h5>
                                    <p>
                                        Possibilidade de imprimir relatório das vendas realizadas.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end 6 col-->

                    </div><!--end of row-->
                </div>

            </section>

            <section class="side-image clearfix">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 content col-sm-8 clearfix">
                            <h1>Visualize suas vendas no Portal Rede Midas</h1>

                            <ul class="blog-snippet-2">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="icon icon-documents"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <a href="#">Visualize seu extrato</a>
                                        <span class="sub alt-font">Por data/hora, valor e diversas outras possibilidades.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="icon icon-calendar"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <a href="#">Histórico detalhado</a>
                                        <span class="sub alt-font">Visalize detalhadamente o que você já recebeu e o que irá receber.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="icon icon-newspaper"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <a href="#">Diversos Relatórios</a>
                                        <span class="sub alt-font">Disponibilizamos diversos relatórios para visualizar de qualquer lugar do mundo.</span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>                                                           
                            </ul>   

                            </div><!--end of row-->


                    </div><!--end of container-->
                </div>

                <div class="image-container col-md-5 col-sm-3 pull-right">
                    <div class="background-image-holder">
                        <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/hero10.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>

            <section class="clients-2">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client1.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client2.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client3.png">
                        </div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client1.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client2.png">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
                            <img alt="Client Logo" src="img/client3.png">
                        </div>                        

                    </div><!--end of row-->
                </div><!--end of container-->
            </section>

                <div class="container" id="sobre">
                    <ul class="selector-content">
                        <li class="clearfix active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                                    <h1>A Rede Midas está preparada para levar o mundo de pagamentos onde a sua empresa estiver.</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--end of row-->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <p class="lead">
                                        <h2>Nossa História</h2>
                                        Neste momento, um sonho nasceu em um grupo de Empreendedores, pioneiros em tecnologias de ponta e mercado financeiro (Fintech). Em 2010 a Rede Midas foi fundada e em pouco tempo já havia conquistado a confiança de clientes, fornecedores e parceiros, além das maiores empresas globais de processamento de cartões para atuar com força e foco total no mercado brasileiro.

                                    </p>    
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <p class="lead">
                                    <h2>O que fazemos</h2>  
                                    A Rede Midas é uma empresa autorizada para processar pagamentos eletrônicos em todo o brasil. Disponibilizamos diversos meios de captura, processamos a transação realizada com cartões de crédito, com garantia e segurança para o lojista.
                                    </p>                                
                                </div>

                            </div><!--end of row-->
                        </li><!--end of individual feature content-->

                        <ul>
                </div>          
            <section class="no-pad clearfix">

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 no-pad">

                    <div class="feature-box">

                        <div class="background-image-holder overlay">
                            <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/header2.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="alt-font text-white">rede midas</span>
                            <h1 class="text-white">A solução de pagamento que expande os horizontes do seu négócio.</h1>
                            <p class="text-white">
                                Porque não há limites para o aumento de suas vendas...
                            </p>
                            <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-white">Junte-se a nós</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 no-pad">

                    <div class="feature-box">

                        <div class="background-image-holder overlay">
                            <img class="background-image" alt="Background Image" src="img/hero8.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="alt-font text-white">Valores</span>
                            <h1 class="text-white">Trabalhamos continuamente para o sucesso da sua empresa.</h1>

                            <a href="credenciamento.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-white">Junte-se a nós</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>

            <section>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
                            <i class="icon icon-jumbo social_twitter"></i>
                            <div id="tweets" data-widget-id="622860566718193664">

                            </div>
                            <p>
                                Siga-nos<strong><a href="#">@redemidas</a></strong> para visualizar nossas atualizações
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of row-->
                </div><!--end of container-->
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-container">


            <footer class="short bg-secondary-1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <span class="sub">Copyright © 2015 - Rede Midas. Todos os direitos reservados.</span>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="Junho2015TermoAdesaoMidasCartorio.pdf">Contrato de Credenciamento</a></li>                             
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                            <ul class="social-icons">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/redemidas">
                                        <i class="icon social_twitter"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/redemidas.net">
                                        <i class="icon social_facebook"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>   
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of row-->
                </div><!--end of container-->
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/spectragram.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scrollReveal.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/twitterFetcher_v10_min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly for me. Possibly it's your browser?

Comment: Have you tried loading the site as http://redemidas.com.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.php ? (With index.php appended)

Comment: probably the content type header

Comment: Which browser did you use? Tried id on Chrome and Safari, both download a file.. I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.5 @Ben Morris

Comment: Try <?php header('Content-Type:text/html'); ?>

Comment: content type is set to "application/octet-stream"

Comment: How can I Fix it, @Danijel?

Comment: I tried it on (yes) Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7

Comment: *Gotta love guesswork*. Question would've most likely been solved within seconds, if the OP posted their code. We're now over 15 mins. into this, and still "nothing".

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited the OP with the code... but it wasn't hard to get the code, it's a web page after all..

Comment: you wanted us to actually download that file? say it isn't so.

Comment: I'll bet if you removed `<?php header('Content-Type:text/html'); ?>` magic will happen. You sure you're not including anything?

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio: html is utterly useless, since it's a server-side problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey, no magic did happen, it wasn't there originally, I added following Garr Godfrey tip, but no luck, the result is the same, with or without that line

Comment: @MarcB I thought so, but I'm new to AWS S3, do you know to fix it?

Comment: Try adding a charset `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Still no magic, @Fred-ii- =(

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Check your logs also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No erro, just download the file again..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried adding a simples HelloWorld PHP as index, still download..

`<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Teste</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo "<p>Olá Mundo</p>"; ?>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- found the problem, it's server side..

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio great. what was it? edit: never mind, I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did research a bit more, it's really a server side problem. Amazon S3 can't run PHP files, only static content. Looks like I'll need to use Amazon EC instead, set up a linux server, configure it, and then run the site there.

Answer (score 1):

amazon s3 is storage cloud. You can't host a website on that.Please refer to amazon ec2 for hosting of the site

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. You can host a static website on S3. You can't however host a dynamic website on S3 such as Diego Patrocinio is attempting.

Comment: @mbaird i meant only in this context because of the php codes that i saw inside the source